# How to swap column names in pyspark?

Tags: function, pyspark

How to dynamically swap the column name in pyspark?

**Source data:**

| field_1 | field_2 | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value_1 | value_2 | value_3 |

**Target Data:**

| field_1 | field_2 | source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value_2 | value_1 | value_3 |

I have a list of fields for which I need to do this swap on the fly, without dropping other fields.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`.withColumns()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumns.html) function and provide the dictionary with the column names.

```
df =spark.createDataFrame([('value_1','value_2','value_3')],['field_1','field_2','value'])

#+-------+-------+-------+
#|field_1|field_2|value  |
#+-------+-------+-------+
#|value_1|value_2|value_3|
#+-------+-------+-------+

df.withColumns({"field_2":col("field_1"),"field_1":col("field_2")}).show(10,False)

#+-------+-------+-------+
#|field_1|field_2|value  |
#+-------+-------+-------+
#|value_2|value_1|value_3|
#+-------+-------+-------+
```